# Casting A String To An Int From A JTextField In Java

Tags: java, swing, parsing, int, textfield

So I'm trying to use the text entered in a `TextField` as an `Int`... heres my code

```
int command1 = (int) (command.getText());
```

But I get the error `"Cannot cast from string to int"` an I can't figure it out... can anyone help?

p.s. the text in the `TextField` is not numbers so

```
int command1 = (int) (Double.parseDouble(command.getText()));
```

Will not work...

Comment: if the string is not numeric - what do you want for it's int value?

Comment: What do you expect to come out as an int if "The Text In The TextField Is NOT Numbers"?  By the way, this is English, not German, so stop capitalizing every word.

Answer (score 3):

You need to parse the string containing the integer, not simply cast it.

```
int aInt = Integer.parseInt(aString);
```

Edit: "P.S. The Text In The TextField Is NOT Numbers "   you can't create an int out of something that is not a number.  "ABC" cannot be an int.

Comment: make sure that you enclose it in a try catch block

Comment: @ Zach Follette if you found the answer to be helpful, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @MaVRoSCy Good catch, that way if it isn't an Int, it doesn't bomb your program

Comment: i forgot i could use "String" oops sorry

Answer (score 1):

**Use the Integer wrapper object...**

```
int iVal = Integer.parseInt(String);
```